# Custom mount hard drive on boot

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, fuse

I have a partition on my hard drive formatted as APFS. Linux has no support for APFS filesystems but I found the [apfs-fuse](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse) driver which works fine for my needs (I only need read-only support).

I am able to mount the partition with the following command:

```bsh
apfs-fuse -o uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mac_data
```

Where `/dev/nvme0n1p5` is my APFS partition.

I am simply wondering how I can get this to mount on startup, ideally in a way that exposes command output to the system logs (maybe registering as a startup service?). I would like to avoid using my `~/.bash_login` because I would like to mount this regardless of which user logs in.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "official" way would be to setup a systemd service that executes this command when the system starts up. The "easy" way would be to set up a cron job that runs the command on reboot. The venerable `cron` is nowadays setup trough `systemd` by default on an Ubuntu install, so officially supported. A third, easy easy way would be to run the command from the venerable `rc.local` script. This, however, is not anymore by default setup in a default Ubuntu install since several versions.